# PHP & MySQL SELECT Substring

Tags: php, mysql

`$content` is a variable with a 'detailed description'.
`product_id` is column which might contain a substring of the detailed description (`$content`) in a MySQL table called `products`

I am trying to create a select statement that would find a record if the `product_id` is CONTAINED in the `$content` variable. Then I want to update another table called `receive_sms` with the `url` field from the SELECT staement
Researching on the website I have come up with the following.... But it doesn't work

```
$mysqlic = mysqli_connect("testsms.cloudaccess.net", "username", "password", "testsms2");
$prod_res=mysqli_query($mysqlic,"SELECT url from products
                                 WHERE %product_id% LIKE %$content%");
mysqli_query($mysqlic,"INSERT INTO recieve_sms (comments) VALUES ('$prod_res')");
```

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
$prod_res = mysqli_query($mysqlic, "SELECT url from products
                                    WHERE '$content' LIKE CONCAT('%', product_id, '%')");
```

or:

```
$prod_res = mysqli_query($mysqlic, "SELECT url from products
                                    WHERE LOCATE(product_id, '$content') != 0");
```

You need to put `$content` in quotes.

Actually, it would be better if you used a prepared query, then `'$content'` would become a placeholder `?`.

After you query, you need to call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to get the column value:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prod_res);
$url = $row['url'];
```

Comment: Unfortunatelty, it still doesn't work. After doing some more research on this site, could it be the variable I am assigning to the SELECT statement. Should I use the SET command to assign the $prod_res variable?

Comment: `mysqli_query()` doesn't return the value of the column in the `SELECT`. You have to call a fetching function, and then get the value from it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Barbar. You are a genius. I really appreciate your help . it works perfectly. (I have spent hours searching for this)

Comment: Hours? isn't this straight out of the examples in the mysqli documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, I don't understand why you're using wildcards on you field name. You want to check if a value is contained within the value of that field, consider changing this:

```
... WHERE %product_id% LIKE %$content%);
```

to

```
... WHERE product_id LIKE '%$content%');
```

Also, please, use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection. You're using MySQLi, which supports them.

**EDIT**

Also, the return of a `mysqli_query` is a MySQLi Resource. You'll have to fetch the results from the resource to gain access to the value you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Very valid point. How do I not use mysqli. I'm new to php and MySQL. most of what ive learned is by looking at other code on this forum

Comment: You need quotes around `'%$content%'`. But this is the opposite of what the question asked for. This finds records where `$content` is contained in `product_id`, he said _product_id is contained in $content_.